# Eclipse: compile errors when processing maven-apt-plugin-generated source files

Tags: eclipse, m2eclipse

I have a project that uses JPA QueryDSL. For that we use the `com.mysema.maven:maven-apt-plugin` to generate the so-called Q-classes (i.e. Java-code) in Maven phase `generate-sources`. The generated files are placed into directory <project_root>/target/generated-sources.
Subsequently, in phase `process-sources` we execute the `org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin` to add that directory to the source path.
Finally that Java code then gets compiled in phase `compile`.

This setup works all fine when executing the build on the Maven command line.

When I try to run the build inside Eclipse I always get compile errors in some of the generated classes stating that it can not find one of the other generated classes that it refers to (some of the generated classes refer to other generated classes).

That class which is flagged as missing, however, *does* exist, but it seems as if the Eclipse compiler starts compiling the generated sources right away before the generation of all those files is complete, in this case before a class A is generated to which the generated class B refers to.

This is using the currently latest Eclipse version (2022-12) and I have defined M2E lifecycle mappings to execute these two plugins on configuration but not on incremental builds:

```
...
<execute>
    <runOnConfiguration>true</runOnConfiguration>
    <runOnIncremental>false</runOnIncremental>
</execute>
...
```

(I have also given it a try to run them on incremental builds but that didn't change anything.)

Any idea how to teach the Eclipse compiler to wait with compilation until ALL generated files are fully generated? Or any other idea why the Eclipse compiler apparently doesn't "see" files that *have* been generated?

Hope I could make myself clear...

Comment: Since Eclipse 2022-09 [m2e-apt](https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core/blob/master/RELEASE_NOTES.md#inclusion-of-m2e-apt-plugins-for-annotation-processors) is included, but disabled by default; can be enabled in the preferences _Maven > Annotation Processing_ or in `pom.xml` via the property `<m2e.apt.activation>jdt_apt</m2e.apt.activation>`; when enabled, _Project > Properties: Java Compiler > Annotation Processing_ will be automatically configured.

Comment: Thanks for that hint! After setting that flag the module at hand finally built OK, however, suddenly other modules depending on it, showed errors. Additionally setting Maven : Disable Workspace Resolution on all these projects then finally did the trick. The latter I find a pity, but if the build gets more stable with this, so be it. Thanks again for the pointer!

Comment: Glad it's working now. Could you please give a self-answer to help others?

Comment: Unfortunately this solution seems unstable! :-(  
This morning, after starting up Eclipse again, I suddenly had those very same errors again, i.e. generated classes that were missing other generated classes. Of course I had *not* disabled the described flag. In fact, I meanwhile also added the `m2e.apt.activation>jdt_apt</m2e.apt.activation>` property to my pom.xml. But I now still get those errors again. :-(

Comment: I have now built the project once "externally", i.e. on the maven command-line and now eclipse is happy again and shows no more errors, but IMHO this is *not* as it should be! Something must still be missing here (or in the m2e-apt extension or its configuration).

Comment: A few days later: oddly, it now has "stabilized". That effect that these errors re-surfaced and I had to build externally to silence them has not reappeared for a week or so and over several "Build Clean...". So I guess I'll declare it a working solution after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Eclipse >=v2022-09 (according to @howlger, I myself only tested it with v2022-12) the issue is fixed by specifying `<m2e.apt.activation>jdt_apt</m2e.apt.activation>` in the `pom.xml`'s properties section.

Caveats:

1. for our multi-module project I had to select Maven --> Disable Workspace resolution for several modules that still showed errors despite that setting.
2. with these settings the build now succeeds and shows no more errors - albeit only after a few days of "burn-in" (c.f. my misc. comments). Initially those "class-not found" errors re-surfaced for a few days, but then for some reason disappeared. Maybe that disappearance has to do with my removal of the old "lifecycle-mappings" for said plugin from the `pom.xml`.